# jquery modal dialog not closing properly

Tags: jquery

I am configured to show three jquery modal dialogs in same page on differnt button click in ASP.NET site
First I open the first modal dialog and close it, it is working fine
Then I open second dialog, it shows error in console as Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function.
My code is:

```
 function opendialog(url, Id) {
    var h = $(window).height();
    var w = $(window).width();

    h = h - (h * 25 / 100);
    w = w - (w * 25 / 100);
    var jobId = '<%= Request.QueryString["JobId"] %>';
    $('#PreviewCV').load('Admin/PreviewCV.aspx?URL=' + url + '&h=' + parseInt(h) + '&w=' + parseInt(w) + '&applicationID=' + Id + '&jobId=' + jobId, function () {
        return false;
    });
    var $dialog = $('#PreviewCV')
          .dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: false,
              height: h,
              width: w,
              title: 'Preview CV',
              beforeClose: function (event, ui) {
                  $("div#PreviewCV").empty();
              },
              open: function (type, data) {

              },
              close: function (type, data) {
              }

          });

    $dialog.dialog("open");

}

  function AddNotes(jobApplicationId, candidateId,jobId) {

    $('#ContactLog').load('Admin/AddNotes.aspx?CandidateId=' + candidateId + '&JobApplicationId=' + jobApplicationId + '&JobId=' + jobId, function () {
        return false;
    });
    var $dialog1 = $('#ContactLog')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: false,
                height: 600,
                width: 850,
                title: 'Add Notes'                 
            });
            $dialog1.dialog('open');
}

 function openLetterdialog(comment) {

    $('#PreviewCoveringLetter').html(comment);
    var $dialog2 = $('#PreviewCoveringLetter')
          .dialog({
              autoOpen: false,
              modal: false,
              height: 350,
              width: 400,
              title: 'Preview Covering letter',
              open: function (type, data) {

              },
              close: function (type, data) {

              }

          });

          $dialog2.dialog("open");

}
```

How to solve this issue?What I did wrong in this code.

Thanks & Regards,
Lalitha

Comment: Is $dialog1 the one with the error?

Comment: No.  I dont know, when i open the modal dialog and close it, then I open next dialog, it shows this error. I am not opening in order basis

Comment: a jsfiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net ) whould help a lot to understand.